# CSS:Fix image outside the body of container

Tags: css, sass

I have to fix a blue colored 'lock' image to the outside of the container like below:

[image]

So far I have achieved this below:

[image]

I am setting this image as background-image of the container and the CSS for the container I wrote is:

```
.container{
margin: 0 auto;
max-width: 620px;
background-color: $white;
box-shadow: 0 1px 3px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
object-fit: contain;
margin-top: 30px;
padding: 40px;
min-height: 100px;
object-fit: contain;
overflow: hidden;
border-radius: 5px;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-image: url("../lock.svg");
}


<body>
<div class="container">

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

If I give background-position, the image is hiding behind the container, like this

[image]

Please advice how to achieve this? Is my approach correct?

Comment: Paste your full code here .

Comment: `background-position`.

Comment: paste your HTML code brother. .

Comment: added the html code as well

Comment: I decided to delete my answer, since I disagree with users that doesn't promote quality content with both upvotes and accepts. If you decide to start uphold SO policies [Accepting Answers?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/255093), I will start pay attention to your future questions.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to set your lock button depending on the container, you have to set a relative position to the container and an absolute position to the button.

Then you set top and right property to the button depending on the container.

```
.container {
    position: relative;
}

.button {
    position: absolute;
    top: some px;
    right: some px;
}
```

Comment: This works but if we re-size the window the lock image is not correctly positioned.